# Angular [cdkCopyToClipboard] beeing called repeatedly

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using the `ClipboardModule` from `@angular/cdk/clipboard` to copy data from my angular form, the problem is that i just realized that my `CopyDeatils()` method is being called **continuously** but the value is only copied when the button is pressed.

here is my code:

```
CopyDetails(): string {       
        return "details ...";       
    }
```

and this is how it is being called:

```
<button [cdkCopyToClipboard]="CopyDetails()" type="button">Copy</button>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you're using default change detection. In that case the function will be called multiple times based on refresh cycle. You could instead bind the `cdkCopyToClipboard` to variable and use either `mouseup` or `click` event handler to bind the function. Try the following

Controller

```js
copyToClipboard: string;

CopyDetails(): string {
  ...       
  copyToClipboard = "details ...";       
}
```

Template

```html
<button 
  (mouseup)="CopyDetails()"
  [cdkCopyToClipboard]="copyToClipboard" 
  type="button"
>Copy</button>
```

Edit: move `(mouseup)` event handler before `[cdkCopyToClipboard]` binding based on OP's comment

Comment: It worked thanks! but must add the `click` event before the `cdkCopyToClipboard` in order to get the value correctly.